# Get and set an image URL via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the image URL from an "img" tag and then set it in another tag. I'm trying to use the attr() function to set the src text of the image but is not working.

```
var n_rows = $('#r_data_5').text();
var data = $('#datos_ocultos > ul > li');
var index = 0;
for (let i = 0; i< parseInt(n_rows); i++){
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 var src = data.eq(index).find('#r_data_4').attr('src');
 img.attr('src', src);
}
```

```
<div id="datos_ocultos" style="display: none;">
 <p class="report_data" id="r_data_5">
  <t t-esc="number_rows" />
  </p>
  <ul>
   <t t-foreach="report_ids" t-as="report">
    <t t-if="report.teacher_id and report.subject_id">
     <li>
      <p class="report_data" id="r_data_0">
       <t t-esc="report.teacher_id.name " />
      </p>
      <p class="report_data" id="r_data_1">
       <t t-esc="report.subject_id.display_name " />
      </p>
      <p class="report_data" id="r_data_2">
       <t t-esc="report.course_id.display_name " />
      </p>
      <p class="report_data" id="r_data_3">
       <t t-esc="report.teacher_id.work_email " />
      </p>
      <img t-att-src="'/web/image/hr.employee/%s/image' % report.teacher_id.id" width="96" height="65" id="r_data_4"/>
//more code
```

Uncaught TypeError: img.attr is not a function

Any suggestion? Thanks for reading!
[image]

Comment: `img.src = src` will do just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`img` is DOM element, since it is not a jQuery referenced element you can not use jQuery's [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) on that. You can either use jQuery:

```
$(img).attr('src', src);
```

**OR:** Use the equivalent vanilla JavaScript method [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
img.setAttribute('src', src);
```